# how to get rid of weird lines showing on my vim windows after omni completion

Tags: vim, cmd, omnicomplete

[image: weird lines in windows vim after omni completion]

Every time after using omnicomplete in vim it gives suggestions in a pop up after my cursor and when I'm done with it, it leaves a line along the pop up.. and it only goes away after scrolling the complete window once. It gets very annoying..

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: That's a rendering problem: I doubt doing anything in Vim will will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use CTRL-L? It should redraw the screen.

```
:h CTRL-L
```

Comment: yes it does erase all the lines.. but I had to do it every time.. how can i stop those lines from appearing..

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a rendering bug.

Step 1: try downloading the latest Vim source code and compiling it

Step 2: see if the problem exists there

Step 3: if the problem still exists, report as a bug on the vim_dev mailing list ( http://www.vim.org/maillist.php#vim-dev ). Be sure to specify your Vim version, whether you're using terminal or GUI Vim, and on what OS.

Step 4: wait anywhere from a few days to a few years and maybe somebody will fix it